# Laravel 4 collection only returning first row

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have many to many relationship and what I am trying is to get all rows from the pivot table based on a certain advertisement id.

**My tables:**

advertisements table

[image]

images table

[image]

advertisements_images

[image]

**My models:**

Image.php

```
class Image extends Eloquent
{

protected $table = "images";

/**
 * 
 * @return type
 */
public function advertisements()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Image', 'advertisements_images', 'img_id', 'adv_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = $value . date('YmdHis');
}

}
```

Advertisement.php

```
class Advertisement extends Eloquent
{

protected $table = "advertisements";
public static $sluggable = array(
    'build_from' => 'title',
    'save_to' => 'alias'
);

public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Advertisement', 'advertisements_images', 'adv_id', 'img_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Advertisement', 'advertisements_categories', 'adv_id', 'cat_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Method inside controller

```
private function selectMainImage($id)
{
    $images = \Advertisement::find($id)->images;
    $temp = array(array());
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $temp[$i]['id'] = $image->id;
        $temp[$i]['name'] = $image->name;
        $temp[$i]['url'] = \MyThumbnails::get($image->id, "125x125");
        $i++;
    }
    $data = array(
        'title' => 'Odaberite glavnu sliku',
        'id' => $id,
        'images' => $temp
    );
    $this->generateView('layout.backend.advertisement.main-image', $data);
}
```

This method should return a view with all 6 images, instead it returns only the first image.
When I do a var_dump() on a collection I get this which returns only the first row: http://paste.laravel.com/18up
If I create duplicate advertisements in the database the collection will return first and second row. And if I do it again will return row + 1 untill all images are displayed.

Example of duplicate:

[image]

[image]

http://paste.laravel.com/18uy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the relationships wrong.

```
class Advertisement extends Eloquent{
...
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Image', 'advertisements_images', 'adv_id', 'img_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
...
}
```

And

```
class Image extends Eloquent{
...
public function advertisements(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Advertisement', 'advertisements_images', 'img_id', 'adv_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

What you wrote wrong is the Model they belong to: `Image->belongsToMany('Advertisement')` and `Advertisement->belongsToMany('Image')`. Try to see if this is enough to fix it... the rest seems good to me

Comment: Okay will try that now.

Comment: @VladimirJelovac... I've been through it, I know the pain ;)